# Mocha's describe "require() is missing" in WebStorm 11

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, webstorm

I've just installed WebStorm 11 and created a new project, however WebStorm is saying that a `require()` is needed for the `describe` method:

[image: require() call is missing]

I've added the definitely-types mocha library and the scope is for the test directory (which this file is in).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Edit: As noted in the comments, the actual issue addressed in this question is actually a bug in IntelliJ 15 / WebStorm 11 (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18768).  I'm leaving the answer below because many people come here when searching for the solution provided.

2023 edit: Looking back at this, I think that if you include the `@types/mocha` or `@types/jest` or `@types/node` entries in your package.json dev dependencies, then IntelliJ will pick them up automatically now.

The accepted answer is a sledgehammer approach to solving the problem.  A better solution is to enable the mocha-DefinitelyTyped library for the test directory.  Not only will this remove the erroneous inspection, it will provide better syntax highlighting.

From the description of the inspection:

> When using libraries that define their own global symbols outside
> their visible JavaScript code (e.g. `describe()` in Mocha), it is
> recommended that you add the corresponding TypeScript type definition
> file as a JavaScript library in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks |
> JavaScript | Libraries.

Navigate to the preference section referenced above, ‘Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries’, and check if the mocha-DefinitelyTyped library is in the list.

If `@types/mocha` (used to be named `mocha-DefinitelyTyped`) is not in the list, click the `Download…` button, find ‘mocha’ in the ‘TypeScript community stubs’ section, select it, and click Download and Install:

[image: ‘mocha’ library to import, shown in the Download Library window]

The library is named just `mocha` in the list, but will convert into `@types/mocha` (prior to early 2019, it would convert to `mocha-DefinitelyTyped`) once imported.

Once you have mocha-DefinitelyTyped, uncheck its Enabled checkbox. Leaving it fully checked would enable it globally, even outside of tests, which would be inaccurate. Instead, we will manage its scope to be enabled only in your test directory. Click the `Manage Scopes…` button, find your test directory, click on the Library column, and select the ‘mocha-DefinitelyTyped’ entry.  See the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of the JavaScript Libraries Usage Scopes preferences window]

Comment: This is amazing. Is there a tool to download dependency typings like this to a global folder? I've set up a global `typings` directory that I'm referencing from WebStorm now but it takes 1-2 minutes per dependency to set up.

Comment: @Brian, I don't believe so.  IntelliJ downloads them into its own cache, but manages them by project.

Comment: @BamaPookie I currently have common typings in a directory outside of the project. I know I need to reference that directory in each project manually. Writing a tool to go through your dependencies, checking to see if their typings exist in your typings directory, and downloading the ones that don't could be a pretty cool project. I looked and I don't see anything like that around. It would have to be a global module you could run for each project.

Comment: @BamaPookie - apparently the vs code team had the same idea with disastrous results http://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_7#_171-recovery-build

Comment: when talking about the problem initially logged, this answer is completely wrong, as in WebStorm 11 the error was still reported despite having Mocha stubs installed. See the problem description: `I've added the definitely-types mocha library and the scope is for the test directory`. Problem was solved in 2016.x by fixing https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18768 linked to the correct answer

Comment: @lena you are absolutely correct.  Unfortunately, many people come to this issue when searching for the problem of missing type mappings unrelated to the bug.  I can modify the answer to include this caveat, if you like.

Comment: @BamaPookie That would be kind of you.:)

Comment: My problem was with underscore but this helped me add the js library to avoid the problem, thanks

Comment: Still working in 2023!! In the 'manage scopes' window, you now have to click the + button and navigate to your test folder in the popup, hit OK, and then select the library (may be just the new UI).

Comment: Looking back at this, I think that if you include the `@types/mocha` or `@types/jest` or `@types/node` entries in your package.json dev dependencies, then IntelliJ will pick them up automatically now.

Answer (score 10):

This is a new inspection introduced in v. 11 - it checks if the module used in code is referenced through require() statement. This inspection, indeed, is redundant for mocha tests ('describe' and other stuff don't need being required explicitly as they are added to global scope by Mocha). You can either disable this inspection or suppress it for 'describe', 'it', etc (see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/suppressing-inspections.html).
Another option: create a custom scope with your spec files excluded (Settings/Appearance & Behavior/Scopes), then choose this scope for 'Missing require() statement' inspection (Settings/Editor/Inspections/Javascript/Node.js).

Related ticket: [WEB-18768](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18768)

Comment: "You can either disable this inspection or suppress it for 'describe', 'it', etc." - please elaborate.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html  - so preferences -> Editor -> Inspections -> JavaScript -> Node.js -> Missing require() statement    Then how do i add any suppressions like 'describe', 'it' etc ?

Comment: The only way i could get this to work was with a custom scope, in my case, choosing my test folder and selecting include recursively, then associating that scope with the given inspection rule (and electing to switch the rule off altogether for that scope). I didn't find any way to cleverly adjust the inspection rule itself to ignore a blacklist of items eg. describe, it etc that can be considered global. Please can someone leave a comment here if such an approach exists (using Webstorm 11.0.3)

Comment: the only way to make inspections ignore certain file is setting up the scopes - see my answer above

Comment: This is where I beg to differ - your answer, as it currently stands, eludes to the fact this is possible. Quoting the answer - "You can either disable this inspection or suppress it for 'describe', 'it', etc. Another option: create.."   - so please tell me what you meant before you state "Another option".  how do i suppress it for 'describe', 'it'. Using a scope is taking your "Another option" recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: you can suppress certain inspection for current code statement by hitting Alt+Enter, Right, Suppress for statement. see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/suppressing-inspections.html?search=suppress#1

Comment: thanks for the feedback. personally, i think a tweak to the way the answer is worded would be beneficial. happy to suggest a change if you like, but you are an experience SOF user so leave it to your discretion otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug in Webstorm 2017.3 that prevents installation of Javascript Libraries via the ‘Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries | Download and Install’ method.

It's being tracked here, and the latest EAP (Early Access Preview), (Webstorm 2017.3.2 at the time of writing) fixes the issue.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FWEB-29725

I banged my head against the wall on this for hours, hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have installed mocha globally and if it's still not work then try to remove all Run/Debug Configurations.

It will update npm runner and I hope it solves the problem.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Removing all the run/debug configs isn't really a good solution.

Comment: However I spent a lot of time to fix this issue and no one answer is helped me. I found this solution by myself and I just sharing with my experience. If it is not helped you - does not mean that it will not help others.

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple workaround that will solve the issue for you and for all other developers in the project:

Add the following line at the top of the file:

```
const { describe, it, before, beforeEach, afterEach, after } = require('mocha');
```

Comment: This was relating to WebStorm 11 (nearly five years ago).  At the time this wasn't an option but WebStorm did have methods of marking other files as libraries.