# WebStorm can not find ts-node/module and describe definition when setup with Mocha, Chai and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, webstorm, chai

I am having problems setting up WebStorm with Mocha/Chai and TypeScript.

I installed mocha and chai setup a test script in my `package.json` like so

```
"test": "env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\" }' mocha -r ts-node/register 'tests/**/*.ts'"
```

When I run `npm test` the test runs and everything is fine.

However WebStorm does not recognize `describe` and `it`. Even though I am running WebStorm 2020.3 I followed the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599983/mochas-describe-require-is-missing-in-webstorm-11) without any success.

Furthermore when I use the runner in WebStorm I get the following error:

> ERROR: Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'

In the Runner configuration in WebStorm I added the following:

- Environmental Variables: `env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{"module": "commonjs" }'`
- Extra mocha options: `mocha -r ts-node/register`

[image]

However this also did not help.

What am I missing?

**[Edit]**

Thanks to the comment by lena I found out that the Mocha package was pointing to the wrong project so I fixed it. Unfortunately I now get this error:

[image]

Comment: please share a screenshot of your run configuration

Comment: make sure that the working directory in run configuration is the same you run your npm script in (i.e. the one where your `package.json` is located)

Comment: well unfortunately I now get another error...

Comment: can be related to parsing `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS` variable value... does the issue persist if you remove the option from **Environment Variables**?

Comment: When I remove it I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: OK; and what about not using quotes in variable value? Like `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS={"module":"commonjs"}`? It works fine for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the way your environment variable is defined - remove the single quotes around the value, this is what mocha is complaining about. Just set it to `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS={"module":"commonjs"}`:

[image]

it works fine for me

Comment: thanks thats solves it, however the `describe` and `it` are still not recognized

Comment: where aren't they recognized, in editor? That's because the mocha package doesn't expose its globals, so the only way to get these methods recognized by static code analysis is installing typings (`npm i @types/mocha`).

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

Comment: yes in the editor. I installed `@types/mocha` and I also followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599983/mochas-describe-require-is-missing-in-webstorm-11
which is similar to the one you postet. 
However in my case `described` is red underlines and when I hover over it I get :" ESLint: 'describe' is not defined.(no-undef)"

Comment: the error comes from the linter (ESLint), not from the IDE. You have to configure the linter by setting the `env` accordingly, see https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments